# Finding all .c files in linux using grep

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I have an assignment to specify a linux command in a terminal that finds all the .c files on the system and the file name contains "lab" at the start (in all combinations of case sensitivity), followed by any number within 1-299 range ,followed by the character #, % or &.
Example : lAb72#
For the first part,I know that the command grep **-i** ignores the case sensitivity.

Comment: Hey Selendi, please don't delete your questions unless there is something terribly wrong with them. It's always possible to fix questions.

Comment: Well,apparently I alone were the only one who understood what I meant :P Sorry

Comment: If nobody answers your question, just leave it where it is. It's no shame to have unanswered questions. Maybe some day someone will come and answer it for you? If you find the answer on your own, you can even go and post it, that's great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
find . | egrep "[lL][aA][bB][1-2][0-9][0-9][%&#]\\.c$"
```

Start from the root or `/`  directory, or change the above to `find /` instead of `find .`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex: `find / -regex "[LlAaBb][1-2][0-9][0-9][#%&]"`

Comment: how do I use taht in a terminal ?

Comment: Ty,but it fins alot of files even after I add .c at the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

```
ls lAb*.c    # will list all c file  with starting lAb in same directory

find / -iname "lab[0-9]*[%&#]*.c" -print                # this will list in entire file system
```

Comment: Ty,but that doesen't filter everything as I specified :(